# Azure JWT with property "hasgroups=true" instead of groups property object

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

I have an Azure Web Application with Azure Active Directory authentication (made with adal-angular);

In the application manifest i have set `"groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup"`

The strange thing is that for some days, for just a user, it does not have the group claim in the AAD token with the list of group membership objectIds, but instead there's a property named `hasgroups` with value `true`.

Can I do something about it?
For now I'm going to check if there's one property or the other and then call GraphAPI for direct group membership.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**`hasGroups=true` is returned in the case where there the user belongs to *"too many groups"*.** I don't know what the exact threshold is (20? 200?) but effectively what you need to do in your code is something along the lines of (pseudocode):

```
if (hasGroups)
  Call the Graph to inquire:
    Either about the full group membership OR 
    About membership to a particular group
else
  Access groups directly from the token
```

[Get all the groups a users belongs to](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#GetUsersMemberships):

```
https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/{user_id}/$links/memberOf?api-version
```

[Inquire whether the user belongs to a specific group](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/functions-and-actions?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#isMemberOf):

```
https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users/{user_id}/isMemberOf?api-version
```

Comment: it was 200 the limit, now it's 5 ? the only word i can think of is "unfair"

Comment: the problem was encountered with a profile with membership in 7 security groups

Comment: @MicheleT 7 is the case...strange I thought MS set it to 200, why is it 7?

Comment: I believe it was 200 early on, but it appears to be 5 now... but that is just a bit too restrictive.  Who has 5 or less groups?  I have 23 on my plain user account!

Comment: This limit only applies to access tokens obtained via implicit flow (adal.js, msal.js). Please refer to the detailed answer below?

Comment: No, the limit applies to all flows though the limit is smaller for implicit flow. Quoting the same docs you did: "For other flows, if the number of groups the user is in goes over a limit (150 for SAML, 200 for JWT), then an overage claim will be added to the claim sources pointing at the AAD Graph endpoint containing the list of groups for the user"

Answer (score 2):

Please check if you are using the [Authorization Code grant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code) or the [implicit grant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-implicit-grant-flow)?

The *hasGroups* claim is only provided in case of the implicit_grant and the number of groups provided in the *groups* claim is limited to 6 to as more would extend the URI fragment beyond the URL length limits. Refer to the *hasGroups* and *groups* claim's documentation in [Azure Active Directory access tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens).